# Laravel Many to Many sync with null

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I'm trying to use sync function like that:

```
$round->competitors()->sync($fighters);
```

$fighter is :

```
Collection {#339 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => 5
    1 => null
    2 => 6
  ]
}
```

When it get to the null element, I get :

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'competitor_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `round_competitor` (`competitor_id`, `round_id`) values (, 29))
```

I get the same result if I try:

```
$round->competitors()->sync([null, null]);
```

But if I try:

```
$round->competitors()->attach(null);
```

it works without any problem???

Why is that happening???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `filter()` on your `$fighters` so that the `null` values are removed.

```
$round->competitors()->sync($fighters->filter());
```

Comment: thing is I need a to save it : round = 1, competidor = null, isn't it posible?

Comment: No, that's not how the belongs to many relationship works - it has to connect two models. What's the point of a record that references a round but not a competitor?

Comment: It happens frequently when number of competitors is not perfect. If I have rounds of 3 competitors and a total of 8 competitors, for instance, the last group of 3 will have an empty space. I must maintain this space, I can't just forget it. I can't put a competitor that is the Null one, and use his id, because I also have a UNIQUE condition : $table->unique(['competitor_id', 'round_id']);

Comment: I think perhaps you should maintain that in your application code and keep your data source (the database content) as valid as possible. Putting in a row where a field is `null` is really non-information, not information and probably shouldn't be persisted that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you do: `$round->competitors()->attach(null);` is it the same as if you just don't make any attach? That's probably why it is working!!